# Scraping text with xpath/lxml

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to scrape the text "2005-2013" from the text that says "drink between: 2005 - 2013" from http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=91411 using xpath/lxml, and am only able to do it for some of the other pages on this site, and not this one. Not sure what I'm doing wrong/if the xpath I have been copying from the element is incorrect

it tell's me:

```
print(content_divs[0].text_content().strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's my code:

```
import requests, lxml.html
page = requests.get('http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=91411')
html = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
content_divs = html.xpath('//*[@id="wine_copy_inner"]/p/a[4]')
print(content_divs[0].text_content().strip())
```

thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `"2005 - 2013"` you might use below code

```
content = html.xpath('//a[@title="Source: Community"]/text()')
```

Comment: sorry, I mean I want to get "2005 - 2013" (I've updated my question) though I'm not sure as to why others are able to get this and yet I get the error with the same code.

Comment: Try this one `content = html.xpath('//a[@title="Source: Community"]/text()')`

Comment: sorry to bother you with this again, but I'm not trying to get the "vintage" from the same site, and have used a similar method as you did, but it does not seem to be working. `content_divs = html.xpath('//a[@href="http://cellartracker.com/list.asp?Table=List&Vintage]/text()')`)

Comment: What you mean *vintage*? What exactly you want to get?

Comment: if you go on this page (http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=177807) the vintage is 2004

Comment: You mean this element `<a href="list.asp?Table=List&amp;Vintage=2004">2004</a>`?

Comment: yes, but I need to assume that I won't already know the vintage, and that that is the piece of information I want. so i tried to give only part of the href

Comment: `//a[starts-with(@href, "list.asp?Table=List&amp;Vintage=")]`

Comment: that returns an empty list for me, maybe the site is blocking me?

Comment: I think it's because of ampersand symbol. Try shorter version: `//a[starts-with(@href, "list.asp?Table=List")]`

Answer (score 0):

Is the xpath array zero indexed?

`//*[@id="wine_copy_inner"]/p/a[4]` should be `...[3]`.

Looks like the number of `a` tags changes when you are logged in vs logged out. Might want to use another method to locate this tag.

Comment: tried using beautifulsoup, but was not able to locate the overarching </div> even, not sure if I should be using selenium instead

Comment: Perhaps the content varies. Scraping is always a risk because you relying on the page being consistent all the time, which it's often not.